# Eliminar datos de dos listbox C#

Tags: c#, listbox

Buenas a todos y desde ya agradezco su ayuda,
comento que tengo dos listbox en C#. Uno contiene nombres y otro los números de teléfonos de estos, lo que deseo es que si elimino por ej a Juan del listbox 1 se elimine también su numero de telefono que esta contenido en listbox 2. de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: y como tenes vinculado que el telefono es de juan?

Comment: Saludos. Proporciona lo que realizaste y en que falla (mensaje y/o resultado erróneo); así mismo, como identificas lo que se debe eliminar el `listbox 2` conforme lo que se elimine de  `listbox 1`.

Comment: Yo se que tu pregunta es con listbox. Pero estas seguro que esa es la mejor forma de relacionar dos estructuras. Yo diria que uses un Dictionary<String, String> asi cuando anadas un nombre con telefono seria asi:

`IDictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add("juan","33-33-33");
dict.Add("pedro","44-444-44");`

Y lo accessas con dict["juan"]

Answer (score 0):

Buenas agradezco sus preguntas para ayudarme. me concentre y me dedique a otros puntos pero finalmente logre solucionar mi problema con lo siguiente(tal vez a alguien le sirva mas adelante).

```
string text = lstNombre.GetItemText(lstNombre.SelectedItem);
int indice = lstNombre.SelectedIndex; 
if (indice != -1)                    
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Esta seguro que desea 
           eliminar al contacto:\n" + text, "ADVERTENCIA", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
               MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                lstNombre.Items.RemoveAt(indice);
                lstNumero.Items.RemoveAt(indice);
```